# BIOS Settings with WMI

Tags: bios

If Board manufacturer gives WMI for Windows for accessing/modifying BIOS settings then will it be possible to use same WMI classes to do the same thing but from Linux ?

OR

What information do I required from manufacturer to configure the BIOS settings from within Linux ?